# Getting a value error while using SUMIFS function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, powerquery, excel-2019

[image: Demo picture]

I want the gross amount of each unique email if the days remaining is less than 12 and if the unique email is present in the email column.

I have used SUMIFS function but I am getting a value error.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

For clarity after post edit: `IF(days_remaining>=value, "", SUMIF(email_range, email, gross_value_range))`

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't help me with the expected output

Comment: What is the expected output if the days remaining is greater than or equal to 300 (add to your question if you get a chance)? Replace the "" with that

Comment: I want the gross amount of each unique email if the days remaining is less than 300 and the duplicate email = unique email.

Comment: So what is the expected output if the days remaining is greater than or equal to 300?

Comment: Your edit shows values greater than 12 being blank. That is what my formula does

Comment: the output should be like the gross amount of a@a.com = xxx amount